# Calculate past till this week in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I created a measure that calculate the percentage of all previous weeks, but I want to exclude this week and future.

This is what I have:

% Percentage = ('Measure group'[Payd hours]-'Measure group'[Hours total])/'Measure group'[Hours total]

Which formula should i use?

I search the internet but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to show a measure until a certain date I would recommend using your calendar table to  do so. Simply filter your calendar table to the selected date in order to filter your result.

You can use your current measure and then add the following measure:

```
Percentage measure = 
CALCULATE([% Percentage], CalendarTable[Date] < MAX(CalendarTable[Start Of Week])
```

Or change your current measure to:

```
CALCULATE(DIVIDE('Measure group'[Payd hours]-'Measure group'[Hours total]),'Measure group'[Hours total]),CalendarTable[Date] < MAX(CalendarTable[Start Of Week])
```

Also try to use DIVIDE over / when dividing two numbers. DIVIDE can handle dividing by zero (returning blank or alternate result) while / returns Infinite.

Calendar Table:
https://www.dearwatson.net.au/blog/power-bi-calendar-tables/

Comment: Thanks, this helps me solves the problem.